# Parse counter strike logs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm analyzing counter strike server logs in real time through nodejs.
The goal of the script is to receive logs, parse them and execute actions on the server according to what the log contains.

This is working well, but right now, the script is splitting each log line to find the needed information (user, action).
I would like the script to parse the log with regex, and regex's and I aren't friends...

I made a fiddlejs example: https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyb/ea63g8tz/1/

```
var logs = [
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:2392398293"><T>say "go d2"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:6565233215"><T>say "crap"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:4548512145"><T>say "go inf"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:6565233215"><T>say "stuff"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:4548512145"><T>say "things"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:2392398293"><T>say "war rr"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:4548512145"><T>say "kick t"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:6565233215"><T>say "kick ct"',
    '13-12-2015<"U:1:6565233215"><T>say "kick all"'
];

for (var l = 0; l < logs.length; l++) {
    var log = logs[l],
        re = /<(.*)>/,
        test = log.match(re);
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        add_log(test[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't see how to get in a var the user (U:1:2392398293) and in another var what the user says (go d2).

The use of jquery is only for the fiddle, there is no need for it in the nodejs script.

Thx for reading! English isn't my native language, be easy on me!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific, we don't want to have n questions for "how to parse these kinds of logs"

Comment: Have a look at regexes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: get to know regexes better. They are good friends to have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach , works only for the two cases you mentioned.

```
for (var l = 0; l < logs.length; l++) {
    var log = logs[l], re1 = /\<"(.*)"\>/, re2 = /say "(.*)"/ ;
    test = log.match(re1);
    console.log(test[1]);
    test = log.match(re2);
    console.log(test[1]);
}
```

OR

```
for (var l = 0; l < logs.length; l++) {
    var log = logs[l], re = /\<"(.*)"\>.*say "(.*)"/
    test = log.match(re);
    console.log(test[1] + ' , ' + test[2]);
}
```

I have tested it after replacing your loop part in browser's console.

Answer (score 2):

```
re = /<(.*?)>/

          ^^
```

make your regex non greedy

Comment: good hint to solve the problem, though that does not address the say part directly - capturing between "" might be more to the point.